# How to set React's process.env.NODE_ENV to production on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have set up an AWS Beanstalk environment where I have deployed a React application. I have successfully done it by packaging the project folder to a .zip file and uploading it via the console, as well as through an AWS CodePipeLine.

The problem is that the variable `process.env.NODE_ENV` is set to `development`, instead of `production` when I do this. This means I cannot detect if the application is being run in a production environment instead of development.

I have also tried running `npm run build` to create a build folder of the project, then zipping and uploading that, but my environment throws an error when I do that.

So, my question is: does anyone know what steps I need to take to ensure that `process.env.NODE_ENV` is set to `production` when running on AWS Beanstalk?

Alternatively, if this cannot be done, is there another way to make React differentiate between development and production environment?

Comment: Have you looked at [configuring environment properties](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html#environments-cfg-softwaresettings-console)?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. I added multiple environment property ENVIRONMENT with value prod  via the AWS console, and tried to fetch them via the variable process.env as the documentation suggested, but when I tried that the values were undefined.

When I logged process.env in the console, it showed show a number of values, but none of them were any of the environment properties I had tried adding.

```process.env =  
Object { NODE_ENV: "development", PUBLIC_URL: "", WDS_SOCKET_HOST: undefined, WDS_SOCKET_PATH: undefined, WDS_SOCKET_PORT: undefined, FAST_REFRESH: true }```